# Orientation of resistor when connected in a cicuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current, electrical-resistance

Consider a cuboid shaped resistor.
Now
Case1: Connect the resistor along is length to a battery.

Case2: Connect the resistor along is breadth to a battery.

In the two cases the length and cross-sectional area along and through which current flows are different so resistance should change right? 
Is this correct or the resistance is same in both cases?
[image]

Comment: $R = \rho L/A$ holds. So, which is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my answer, I assume the material of the resistor to be homogeneous and isotropic and described by a local resistivity $\rho$ within Drude's theory of linear conductance.

I further assume, the contacts to the resistive material do not contribute an appreciable contact resistance at the surface of the material. They cover the surface areas of the cuboid which are normal to the current flow.

Let the dimensions of the cuboid be $L_x$, $L_y$, and $L_z$.

Under all these assumptions, the resistance of the cuboid is given by
$$ R = \rho \frac{L}{A},$$
where $L$ is the cuboid's length along the direction of current flow, and $A$ is the cross sectional area normal to the direction of current flow in each of the individual cases mentioned below.

So, driving the current along $x$ leads to
$$ R_x = \rho \frac{L_x}{L_yL_z},$$
driving the current along $y$ gives
$$ R_y = \rho \frac{L_y}{L_xL_z},$$
and driving it along $z$ gives
$$ R_z = \rho \frac{L_z}{L_xL_y}.$$

Comment: Yes so resistance depends on orientation the orientation of resistor.

Comment: It seems a bit counterintuitive to me as resistance and current are scalars. So when we find resistance of general shaped body we have consider direction of current through it and integrate or calculate resistance along that path(direction).

Comment: Current has magnitude and direction, like a vector. This becomes better visible, if you use Ohm's law in the form $\vec{E} = \rho \vec{j}$, where $\vec{E}$ is the electric field inside the conductor (related to voltage) and $\vec{j}$ is the current density (related to current).

Comment: @flaudemus then what about resistance. Are orientation dependent quantities necessarily vectors..?

Comment: @hawexrutile: in general, the resistivity $\rho$ is a tensor (matrix) quantity. Only in isotropic materials it can be represented as a scalar.

Answer (score 4):

More generally, the resistance depends on the position of the connections *and* the shape of the conductor.

Comment: Yes that sounds more appropriate and intuitive. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The resistance of the cuboid will be

$$R=ρ\frac{L}{A}$$

Where $ρ$ is the resistivity of the material (Ohm-m) and is assumed the same through out the material and in every direction. $L$ is the length (m) along the current path. $A$ is the area perpendicular to the current path ($m^2$).

The resistance is therefore higher in case 1 than case 2 due to both the length being greater and the area being less than case 2.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes the above cases were just examples my actual doubt was does resistance depend on orientation of resistor which is clear. Thank you.